# MAMP Apache Alias always maps relative to document root

Tags: apache, mapping, alias, mamp

I'm trying to setup a virtual directory in Apache on MAMP.

This is what I'm putting in the httpd.conf file

```
  Alias /app /Users/ernesto/Developer/App/webroot
  <Directory /Users/ernesto/Developer/App/webroot>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

MAMP's document root is set to the default `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` and the path in the example above is meant to be absolute. But MAMP is trying to map the above path to:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Users/ernesto/Developer/App/webroot
```

I realized this after displaying the last few lines of apache's error log:

```
[Thu Nov 17 15:40:39 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Users
```

Just ot be sure, I changes the path above to start with `/Uxers` (instead of `/Users`), and the change was reflected in the error log.

I'm almost sure from what I've researched online that what I expect is the correct behavior, but obviously I might be doing something wrong, or maybe there's some other obscure setting in MAMP's httpd.conf that is making apache work this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So.. from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376590/htaccess-is-ignored-when-using-an-aliased-uri) I got that there are some issues with using both alias and mod_rewrite. Which led me to [this part](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of the Apache manual which states:

```
#
#  /abc/def/.htaccess -- per-dir config file for directory /abc/def
#  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
#            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g.
#

RewriteEngine On

#  let the server know that we were reached via /xyz and not
#  via the physical path prefix /abc/def
RewriteBase   /xyz

#  now the rewriting rules
RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html
```

Adding a rewrite base to the .htaccess file in the aliased directory solved my issue (which led me to your question in the first place)

Comment: This worked, thanks! Default value for RewriteBase is <physical-directory-path> when it should logically be the Alias url. Now RewriteBase has to be specified explicitly in every .htaccess files to correct this. Oviously a bug in mod_rewrite...

Answer (score 0):

I went through this today.  After nearly pulling all of my hair out (I **really** had to get something done work work), I found out found that the include for the httpd-vhosts.conf file was commented out in MAMP's default installation, so none of the (dozens of) troubleshooting changes to my httpd-vhosts.conf file were even taking:

```
...
# Virtual hosts
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
...
changed to 
...
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
...
```

I facepalmed *so* hard.  This is akin to the TV not being plugged in...