# .htaccess is ignored when using an aliased URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp

I am using mod_rewrite to route all requests to index.php.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/Users/Peter/Projects/Framework
    /.htaccess
    /index.php
```

In my .htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works fine when I visit `projects.localhost/framework/example`.

I also have the following alias set up:
    Alias /~alias /Users/Peter/Projects

When I navigate to `http://projects.localhost/~alias/framework/example` I get a 404 error and the following in my error log: `File does not exist: /Users/Peter/Projects/framework/example`

It seems that the .htaccess file isn't being called when I use the aliased URL (typing giberish into the .htaccess file doesn't trigger any kind of error when using the aliased URL seems to confirm this).

AllowOveride is set to All.

How do I get .htaccess working when using the aliased URL and have the rewrite rules apply consistently regardless of the URL (aliased or not aliased)?

Edit: Navigating to `projects.localhost/~alias/framework/index.php/example` also works fine, confirming that the alias is working properly (apart from not having the .htaccess rules applied to it).

Comment: Alias seems to bypass the normal root, and therefore the .htaccess file placed there. You could just put another .htaccess file in the `/Users/Peter/Projects` folder

Comment: I've tried putting a .htaccess file in the projects folder but this also has no affect on the aliased URL. (It does affect the non-aliased url.)

Answer (score 14):

I found your question having the same issue. and from @Gerbens comment I managed to find  [this part](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) of the Apache manual which states:

```
#
#  /abc/def/.htaccess -- per-dir config file for directory /abc/def
#  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
#            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g.
#

RewriteEngine On

#  let the server know that we were reached via /xyz and not
#  via the physical path prefix /abc/def
RewriteBase   /xyz

#  now the rewriting rules
RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html
```

Adding a rewrite base to the .htaccess file in the aliased directory solved my issue.

So in your case

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~alias
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'd vote this up twice if I could -- saved my bacon!  Thanks, @danneth.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. So without RewriteBase, Apache behaves stupidly by assuming its being accessed from the physical path. 
I wonder how this behavior was not reported as a bug.

Comment: For those who are still struggling with this issue. You should try `RewriteBase /your-alias` without the `~`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have mod_rewrite enabled?